# C++ Contact File Program

Tags: c++, makefile, cin

I have a question about my program that I am creating in C++ Visual Studios. First what I want to do is get all the Info about Accounts inputted from the user, then Displayed back to the user to make sure it was entered correctly. Then put that information into the file AccountInformation.txt. I have gotten it to all work up until now it's going from doing this fine `cin >> Street` then it will group the next two cin's together so I don't know why its doing that. here is the code and the sample output of the program as it runs now.

```
// CreateWriteDisplay.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <ostream>
using std::cout;     //using namespace std is not a good practice **
using std::cin;      //it's best to use std:: scope or using only what you need
using std::string;   //not the whole namespace, C++17 allows for comma
using std::endl;     //separated usings
using namespace std;
// Declares all the variables I need.
int AccountAge;
string LastName;
string FirstName;
string Ocupation;
string UserName;
string EmailAdd;
string HomeAddress;
string TeleNum;
string HomeDirectory;
string RoamingProfile;
string Street;
string City;
string State;
string Zipcode;
string YnRoaming;
//macro definitions for max variable length
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_ABOUT_LENGTH 200

int main()
{ 
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH], address[MAX_ADDRESS_LENGTH],
        about[MAX_ABOUT_LENGTH];
//Gets The Accounts Personal Information: Ocupation, Full Name, Age, Email, Home Address, Telephone Number, UserName, HomeDirectory, RoamingProfile,
cout << "Please enter your Ocupation: " << "\n";
 getline(cin, Ocupation); 
 cout << "Enter Your First Name and Last name: " << "\n";
 cin >> FirstName >> LastName;
 cout << "Enter Your Age: " << "\n";
 cin >> AccountAge;
 cout << "Please enter your Email: " << "\n";
 cin >> EmailAdd;
 cout << "Please Enter Your Home Address( ex: 123(enter) Street( Enter), City Name(Enter), State(Enter), Zipcode(Enter)): " << "\n";
 cin >> HomeAddress;
 cout << "Enter Street Name" << "\n";
 cout << "( ex: StreetName st " << "\n";
 cin >> Street;
 cout << "Enter City" << "\n" ;
 cin >> City;
 cout << "Enter State" << "\n";
 cin >> State;
 cout << "Enter Zipcode" << "\n";
 cin >> Zipcode;
 cout << "Please Enter Your Best Telephone Number(EX:508-675-4567): " << "\n";
 cin >> TeleNum;
 cout << "Please Enter Your UserName: " << "\n";
 cin >> UserName;
 cout << "Please Enter Your Account's HomeDirectory(EX:\\HOMEDIRECTORY\\): " << "\n";
 cin >> HomeDirectory;
 cout << "Do you have a Roaming Profile?(Y/N)" << "\n";
 cin >> YnRoaming;
 if (YnRoaming == "Y") {
 cout << "Please Enter Your Roaming Profile Name(IF APPLYS): " << "\n";
 cin >> RoamingProfile; 
 }
 else {
     string RoamingProfile = "N / A";
 }
//getline(cin, HomeAddress);

// Displays All the information entered by the user To verify it was entered correctly.

 cout << "Full Name: " << LastName << "," << FirstName << ", Length: " <<
     FirstName.length() + LastName.length() << "\n" << "Age: " << AccountAge << "\n"
     << "Ocupation: " << Ocupation << "\n" << "UserName: " << UserName
     << "\n" << "Email Address: " << EmailAdd << "\n"
     << FirstName << "'s Home Address" << HomeAddress << Street << City << State << Zipcode
<< "\n" << " Primary Telephone Number: " << TeleNum << "\n" << UserName << "'s Home Directory: " << HomeDirectory 
<< "\n" << UserName << "'s RoamingProfile: " << RoamingProfile << "\n";

// Create  File and Write to it then Close it.
   ofstream MyFile("AccountInformation.txt");
   MyFile << "Full Name: " << LastName << "," << FirstName << ", Length: " << FirstName.length() + LastName.length() << "\n" << "Age: " << AccountAge << "\n"
   << "Occupation: " << Ocupation << ", Length: " << Ocupation.length() << "\n" << "UserName: " << UserName << "\n" << "Email Address: " << EmailAdd << "\n" << FirstName << "'s Home Address"
   << HomeAddress << "\n" << " Primary Telephone Number: " << TeleNum << "\n" << UserName << "'s Home Directory: " << HomeDirectory << "\n"
   << UserName << "'s RoamingProfile: " << RoamingProfile << "\n";
   MyFile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

````
Please enter your Ocupation:
Citizens For Citizens
Enter Your First Name and Last name:
Mark Monhan
Enter Your Age:
24
Please enter your Email:
mmonhan23@gmail.com
Please Enter Your Home Address( ex: 123(enter) Street( Enter), City Name(Enter), State(Enter), Zipcode(Enter)):
524
Enter Street Name
( ex: StreetName st
Street st
Enter City
Enter State
Boston MA
Enter Zipcode
Please Enter Your Best Telephone Number(EX:508-675-4567):
02726 603-854-7845
Please Enter Your UserName:
Please Enter Your Account's HomeDirectory(EX:\HOMEDIRECTORY\):
mgede
Do you have a Roaming Profile?(Y/N)
N
Full Name: Monhan,Mark, Length: 10
Age: 24
Ocupation: Citizens For Citizens
UserName: 603-854-7845
Email Address: mmonhan23@gmail.com
Mark's Home Address524StreetstBostonMA
 Primary Telephone Number: 02726
603-854-7845's Home Directory: mgede
603-854-7845's RoamingProfile:
``` ***
````

Comment: `cin` splits its input on whitespace, and if you give it multiple words as input the following words will pass to later `cin` statements.  Based on your description I bet you are passing a street name with spaces in it.  You need to use `getline` instead if you want to keep whitespace in the input.

Comment: @0x5453 more accurately, it is `operator>>` that splits on whitespace, not `std::cin` itself.  You can use `std::cin.get()`, `std::cin.getline()` or `std::getline()` to read multi-word strings from `std::cin` (or from any `std::istream`)

Comment: oh okay thanx for the advice. But i got my program to work what the problem was that cini leaves a new line character in the buffer so the getline function eats it up and it appears it skipped the getline cin so you need to use cin.ignore(); but thank you

Comment: What made you write `//  Declares all the variables I need.` when that's not what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the line right under the `cin >> EmailAdd;` to be `cin.ignore();` then put `getline(cin, HomeAddress);` that will take the whole Address and store it all in the variable HomeAddress like I want. Theres also some more changes i have implemented to make it run smoother.